# Xcode application bundle ID does not match code signing ID

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, carthage

When I run my project on my iPhone, the error shows up. I have already tried removing all Carthage frameworks and running clean, it works. But once I added back the Carthage frameworks and run it again, the error shows up again. I understand the error has something to do with Carthage but I just do not know how to rectify this. Help is appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I had same issue. Following fixes working for me

Project Target -> Build Setting -> Search "Code signing identity" -> set as follow -> clean build -> Run

[image]

Comment: What did you put for "Provisioning Profile"

Comment: i set "Provisioning Profile"  from general tab. in signin(Debug) - Development profile,  signin(Release) - Distribution profile.